Why don't we call value investing "timing the market"?
This question's been at the back of my mind for some time. The phrase "timing the market" usually comes with some negative connotations, or at least people say it is extremely difficult to do consistently, e.g. in this question. However, it's also widely suggested that value investing (aka "buy great companies at fair prices") works.
Considering that we only buy great companies at fair prices, why don't we call value investing timing the market? It looks highly similar. Suppose I value BigNameCompany and conclude that its stock is worth $50. The price is currently $60, so I don't buy. If the price drops to $40 in the future, then (assuming unchanged circumstances), I buy. I've timed the market, haven't I? Similarly, if the price is currently $40 and it rises to $60, because I value the stock at $50, it seems sensible to sell, therefore timing the market.
I am wondering what the fundamental difference is, if there is one, between value investing* and timing the market.
*I define 'value investing' as attaching an intrinsic value to a stock and buying it only if the current price is below that.

You're only timing one stock!

In one paragraph you talk about a "fair price", and in another you talk about the "intrinsic value" of a stock. To clarify, do you believe that these are equivalent, and are you using them interchangeably?

@Sneftel I think they're approximately equivalent.

@allure of course that's timing the market. The point is - it is irrelevant how you came to the conclusion that now is the right timing, therefore the timing part and the value investing part are completely unrelated. If you think the fair value is 0 but the future meme stock value will be 100, you can "time" the market in the exact same manner as if you think the fair value is 100. Completely independent.


Suppose I value BigNameCompany and conclude that its stock is worth $50. The price is currently $60, so I don't buy. If the price drops to $50 in the future, then (assuming unchanged circumstances), I buy. I've timed the market, haven't I?

What you're describing is the opposite of value investing. Value investing is valuing a stock at $50, seeing that it's selling for $40 in the market, and buying it at $40. If it rises to $50 and you think it's still worth $50, you would sell and look for better opportunities to profit - you have no fundamental reason to think that the stock will rise to $60.
"Timing the market" is wanting to buy a stock (or even to invest in general), but deciding to wait until it goes down in price to buy (because stocks naturally go up and down) hoping to catch a little extra profit. The risk is that stock tend to go up more than they go down, so the odds are against you. It's more likely that you'll buy at a higher price if you wait.

What you're describing is the opposite of value investing - I don't see, if you value it at $50 and buy it at $50, then you're getting a great company for a fair price, no?

But value investing is not about getting a fair price, it's about getting it at a good price. It's buying below it's value expecting that it will eventually realize that value.

@Allure This answer is correct. Short-term (day to day) market timing isn't an aspect of value investing. Price stability and solid underlying fundamentals that aren't recognized by speculators is what value investing is about.

@EllieKesselman I don't see any day-to-day mention in the OP.

@DStanley If you put it that way, I edit the $50 to $40.

@Allure You're correct, that timing the market isn't necessarily the same as intraday price volatility, although it sometimes is. Value investments are those that one buys and holds which isn't based on intra day or even short-term inter-day pricing.

@EllieKesselman again, the OP is not about intraday price volatility - how often do you see a $20 daily fluctuation in a $50 stock?

It is true that there is often caution against "timing the market". The general phrase conveyed is often "Time in the market beats timing the market". That suggests it is better to just invest, now, and as part of an ongoing routine, instead of sitting on a pile of cash and waiting for "the perfect moment" to invest.
This advice is quite practical. In a simplest sense, it promotes enforcement of savings, to the benefit of building a good habit and starting the compounding of earnings as soon as possible. It suggests that over time, the market as a whole trends upward, and without a crystal ball to know what will happen in the future, investing sooner is likely to be better than investing 'at the perfect moment'. This advice is directed to individuals who are not 'actively trading', and for such people, standard advice would also typically be to just invest in diversified ETF's.
Picking individual stocks is not generally advised for those without sufficient understanding. At best, it takes significant skill, and at worst, it is a fool's errand to 'beat the market'. What you are suggesting is both things - picking individual stocks, only at a particular price (eg. time, as you point out).
It is not necessarily true that it is a 'bad' thing to do what you are suggesting - but at bare minimum, consider it higher risk, and requiring more advanced knowledge.

@StackExchangeSupportsIsrael No. The advice isn't because you think today's price is the lowest value the market will ever have. It is because barring special knowledge, the market generally rises over time (otherwise why are you investing in it?), and therefore simply investing and forgetting has many benefits, including avoidance of tricking yourself into thinking you have special knowledge, or deferring many years of accumulated growth while you wait for 'the perfect time'. The advice is just "hey, it might not be the best - but you don't know when the 'best' is, so do it early & often".

@EllieKesselman Yes, this answer addresses the OP's definition of "value investing"; waiting for a 'perfect price' goes against a simplistic philosophy of avoiding timing the market.

@StackExchangeSupportsIsrael No. "Lowest it will ever be" = "the price only goes up". "Generally rises over time" = "there will be ups and downs, but if you hold long enough, the value of the stock market rises".

This is not the definition of value-investing that is used by mutual funds, investors, stock analysts, or Warren Buffet. I think Buffet was the original "value investor", or perhaps Benjamin Graham.
Value investments are common stock of companies whose worth, based on fundamentals, is generally not recognized by the market. Examples of fundamentals are price-to-book and price-to-earnings ratios.
The price on any given day shouldn't be part of your criteria for buying (and holding!) a value stock. As others said, value investing isn't about shorter-term (e.g. inter-week or even inter-month) market timing. It is the VERY opposite of market timing.
According to this Wall Street Journal article, What is Value Investing?

...value investing requires plenty of
research and patience... while value stocks have tended to outperform
more-expensive, faster-growing growth stocks, they often lag for years
at a time... if you aren’t interested in picking stocks
yourself, there are plenty of mutual funds and ETFs that can help
follow the strategy for you.

The two broad categories of stocks are value and growth. Growth stocks are the exciting ones: They are expected to be profitable faster than others in the same industry, or even the overall market. Tesla is a growth stock.
Value stocks are different. They are usually companies in mature industries like specialty steel or chemicals, i.e. their products or services are practical. They might have high dividends and stable prices. In other cases, their stock price is lower than it should be, and there are specific reasons to expect the price to increase. This description, from the same WSJ article, is good:

Value investing is more focused on companies that are well established
and are delivering stable revenues and consistent profits.


Sounds like you and I have different definitions of value investing. In the one I'm familiar with (which does not seem uncommon at all even among finance professionals, see e.g. Forbes), Value investors will consider investing in a company whose price is at or below its intrinsic value. Whether the company is growing quickly or not does not matter.

Investopedia says something similar: Value investing is an investment strategy that involves picking stocks that appear to be trading for less than their intrinsic or book value. Value investors actively ferret out stocks they think the stock market is underestimating.

@Allure your definitions are accurate - but what your question describes is wanting to buy a fair value (or overvalued) stock but waiting until the price goes down.  Value investing looks at stocks that are already undervalued.

@DStanley I'm still not seeing it. It's implausible that every stock a value investor looks at will already be undervalued. Some will be overvalued. The next logical step is to wait until it becomes undervalued, i.e., price goes down.

If a value investor determines that a stock of interest is overvalued, then that stock is not a value investment. Just sell puts on it if your think it is overpriced... but that's not what value investing is about.

Value investors look for undervalued stocks, yes not every stock they look at will be undervalued but in those cases they won't buy them. It feels like you're starting from the premise that a value investor wants to invest in specific companies which is not the case - they look at various metrics of many companies and invest in those that are undervalued.

For example, value investors don't say "I want to invest in Tesla because I think it will go up" and then look for a time when it's undervalued. They say "What stocks out there are trading below their fair value" and focus on those.

@DStanley: I wouldn't expect a value investor to stare at one stock all day, waiting for it to go down, but a value investor for whom no stocks are currently cheap enough to be worth buying would wait until something goes down enough to be worth buying, whereupon the value investor would buy it without waiting for it to possibly go down further.

Well, "cheap" is always relative - the law of averages would tell you that there are always cheap and expensive stocks relative to the market average. Value investors can (and do) invest during "high markets" - they are just focused on stocks that they think are cheap relative to their peers.

@DStanley It feels like you're starting from the premise that a value investor wants to invest in specific companies which is not the case - why wouldn't this be true? The value investor wants to invest in wide-moat companies when the price is cheap. They look at many such companies, like TSLA, and assign a specific price at which they are willing to buy. As long as the price is above the price they assigned, they don't buy.

Value investors as I understand it don't say "I want to invest in Tesla because I think it will go up", they say "I want to invest in Tesla because I think it is a good company, and I can buy it at a price that's lower than its fair value".

No, they don't start by looking at specific companies and then deciding if they're "cheap" - they start by looking at certain ratios for many companies (P/E most notably) compared to their peers and then digging deeper to see if they truly are undervalued. If one of those stocks happens to be TSLA then they might buy, but the starting point is the ratios, not the companies themselves.  They are for the most part completely agnostic about what companies they are, only that they meet certain financial criteria to be considered "value" stocks.

Meaning they don't start with a list of companies and then decide if they're "value" stocks, they start with the financial statistics and then dig deeper by looking at the actual companies to determine why they're "cheap".

@DStanley they don't start by looking at specific companies Really? I am under the impression that the first cut is whether the company has an economic moat - and it makes sense to start with a list of companies that you consider to have such a moat. If you start with the list of all "cheap" companies, then you're inevitably going to hit companies you would not have bought anyway, because they don't have such a moat.

@Allure then you are under the wrong impression. An economic moat is only one aspect of value. First, value investors use the rigor of financial ratios of a peer group of companies (e.g. same product, sector, industry, or even service) to do exactly what DStanley said: compare them to see if any are anomalously cheap for no apparent reason. Only after that would they start considering whether an economic moat or other advantages are present.

@Allure You are probably right. I am unfamiliar with "economic moat", but once they get a list of "cheap" stocks they will then do deeper analysis to determine why they are cheap. There may very well be other fundamental issues that prevent them from investing despite meeting the quantitative criteria. My main point is still that the difference is order - timing the market is knowing what you want to invest it and waiting until it's cheap, versus not targeting specific companies and seeing what is already cheap.

Let's use the Wikipedia definition of market timing:

Market timing is the strategy of making buying or selling decisions of financial assets (often stocks) by attempting to predict future market price movements. The prediction may be based on an outlook of market or economic conditions resulting from technical or fundamental analysis.

This is your definition of value investing:

attaching an intrinsic value to a stock and buying it only if the current price is below that.

Yes, I think so, this value investing is a kind of market timing. It fits squarely into the definition.
Maybe it helps a bit if you can explain in your question why you think value investing as you have defined is not market timing.
